# Can someone explain the expression 'daring me to challenge him.'

Tags: meaning

I'm not quite understand the meaning of the expression 'daring me to challenge him' even though I know the translation of words from it. Could some explain what it means in the next phrases?

> ‘He looked me in the eye practically daring me to challenge him.’
>
> ‘He took a step towards me, brown eyes daring me to challenge him.’

Comment: If you know the translation of the words, then you must have made an educated guess about the meaning.  What do you think it is?

Comment: I think 'daring me to challenge him.' in this context means that a person provokes (maybe prompts) someone to contend or argue with him

Comment: Very good. Exactly right. English often uses sight and seeing to mean provocation: *looking for trouble*, *looking to a fight*. And slang -- *the stink eye*, *the hairy eye*,

Answer (score 1):

Great question, sliser! This expression can have two meanings:

1. Using words, actions or body language to try and provoke sometime in a fight/competition
2. Less commonly, the same meaning as #1 but for the purpose of encouraging someone to try harder or perform more effectively